# Find the Closest Match in Excel using data from a Table

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to write a formula in Excel that will find the closest match in one column and return that value, so that it can be used in a SUMIFS formula. I have done some investigating and found that everyone points at this specific formula:

```
{=INDEX(data,MATCH(MIN(ABS(data-value)),ABS(data-value),0))}
```

The issue I am having though is I am trying to convert this to use data from a Table and have this so far:

```
{=INDEX(_CCD01[[#All],[Date]],MATCH(MIN(ABS(_CCD01[[#All],[Date]]-TODAY())),ABS(_CCD01[[#All],[Date]]-TODAY()),0))}
```

But Excel returns a **#VALUE!** error.

What the formula needs to do, is find the closest date in column _CCD01[[#All],[Date]] using TODAY() as the search criteria.

The file with the table and formula can be found here:
[Dropbox Read Only](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxdqb68r0aevjlz/Calculation.xlsx?dl=0)

Any help or thoughts will be appreciated.

Dave

Comment: To let you know, using `0` on the third `MATCH` parameter, you are looking for an exact match (which btw is not the cause of your error itself)

Comment: @JvdV The nature of the function is that there must be an exact match.  The problem is in the `MIN(ABS(…))` part of the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **array formula**.

```
=INDEX(_CCD01[Date],MATCH(MIN(ABS(_CCD01[Date]-TODAY())),ABS(_CCD01[Date]-TODAY()),0))
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

The syntax you were using `_CCD01[[#All],[Date]]` will also return the header row of the column.  There's no need for this, and it is the cause of your `#VALUE!` error.

- The `ABS` function will return a `#VALUE` error (*as the first element*) in the array it returns when applied against the column since the first entry is text.
- And then `MIN` arguments that are error values or text that cannot be translated into numbers cause errors.

Comment: @DavidBrickell That's because you also had the wrong syntax in the formula.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for the info. I was using the ctrl+shift+enter combo but still had the same issue. I will try and change the formula so as not to include the headers, but I am worried that this will prevent me from adding new rows to the table without having to adjust the formula each time. Or do you think that naming the table rows so they are dynamic will help? Like when creating indirect lists from multiple tables to change the list value of option 2 depending on what option you select from option 1...

Comment: @DavidBrickell The proper table references, as I show, will be dynamic. No worries with adding rows

Comment: Thanks Ron, I changed the formula and removed the header reference as you suggested and the formula is working as I needed it to. Also, the rows are dynamic as you say. Thanks for all your help